A question about adverbials


Frankly, he has done this.
He, frankly, has done this.
The best dog, in my opinion, is a golden retriever.


I know these are giving additional information.
In 1, 2 & 3, bold words are considered what?
Are these considered sentence adverbs or something else?

Where did you encounter these sentences? The second doesn’t sound very natural to me.

@PaulTanenbaum What about this sentence: The best dog, in my opinion, is a golden retriever.

"To be frank" would be better than "frankly" IMO, although it's possible that some English speakers would use "frankly" in this way to mean "I'm being frank/honest/rude here".

"Frankly" is an adverb.  It is a "sentence adverb because it is not modifying a particular word in a phrase but is at the top level.
"in my opinion" is a prepositional phrase.  It too is at the top level of the structure.
In 2 and 3, this phrase is inserted parenthetically.
